# Why is $\pi$ the value it is?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

*Why* is the value of  [$\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) 3.141592...(etc.)? Is it a fundamental property of our universe? Or does it follow from our definition of what a circle is, or does it otherwise follow from the way we perceive or describe the universe?

Could a functioning universe have a  different value of $\pi$? Is it a coincidence that it is a transcendental number and could it just as easily have been rational, or is it a fundamental requirement of pi that it is irrational or transcendental?

Apologies if this has been answered already. I have searched, but all I could find is endless descriptions of how to determine the value of $\pi$, but not *why* that is the value of $\pi$. Or is "it just is" the only answer we can currently give?

Comment: This is more of a philosophy question than physics (i.e., "why" vs "how" questions). You could really swap out $\pi$ with anything (e.g., $e$, $\phi$, $\epsilon_0$ and so on) and have the same question. They are the values that they are, nothing physics can say beyond that.

Comment: I guess that's kind of my question though. *Is* it purely a philosophical question? Or is there actually a physical reason that pi is what it is?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't anything physical about it. In base of $\pi$, it's 1. In base $2$, it is $\approx11$.

Comment: "put on hold as primarily opinion-based" - well I guess that's sort of an answer. Interesting place, PhysicsSE!

Comment: I don't think this should be on hold.  Some string theory papers talk about the value of pi under diff. circumstances.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31495/discussion-on-question-by-pepijn-schmitz-why-is-pi-the-value-it-is).

Answer (score 2):

Strange question. This should probably be on MathSE.

There are a million proofs of the irrationality of pi, and why it has to be irrational. You need some reasonable Mathematical knowledge to understand them - it's not like proving the irrationality of root 2. I encourage you to have a look!!

As for the whole "it just is" thing... "It just is" isn't the only answer we can currently give. It's THE answer. Pi is the ratio of the circumference of a circle to it's diameter, among other things. THAT "just is" the case.

Whether it is a fundamental property of our universe is just Philosophy, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31556/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-s-why-is-pi-the-value-it-is).

Answer (score -1):

It might not be as mysterious as it appears.  Pi is only the consequence of converting from one coordinate system (orthogonal) to another (spherical).

This exceeds my cleverness, but I think if one created another coordinate system (with some axes 30 degrees apart instead of 90) then there would be some square roots (which are also irrational) in the conversion equations.

So, I am thinking pi is not much weirder than root 2.  Which is still kinda weird.

Comment: Why is any number weird?

Comment: If physicists can say theories are 'elegant', then I can say numbers are weird.  Irrational numbers are weird because they go on forever, and can only be represented precisely with new symbols such as e or $\pi$.

Comment: 2 goes on forever (2.000000000000000000000.....) and can be represented precisely with the symbol 2.

Comment: But that's not a new symbol, it is one of the original 10 (in our 10-base system).

Comment: I didn't say anything about new & that aspect is irrelevant. Pi isn't the only number to "go on forever" and is represented by a single glyph. *All* numbers 0-9 do that, so pi, in that sense, is not unlike anything already encountered.

Comment: But I did.  You asked why it was weird, and I defined my criteria.  Then you refute my criteria with a false example.

Comment: @KyleKanos at least concede that pythagoras was horrified by irrational numbers?

Comment: Well your definition isn't consistent with your statements elsewhere. Case in point: you claim in your answer that $\sqrt{2}$ is weird, but this does *not* have a single glyph like $\pi$ or $e$. This would either reduce your criteria to "going on forever" (in which case I have a valid counter-example) *or* $\sqrt{2}$ isn't weird (in which case you lied and my counter-example could be wrong).

Comment: @brucesmitherson: The guy who may have discovered that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational was horrified by irrational numbers? Never thought about it.

Comment: @KyleKanos it might be a myth?

Comment: @KyleKanos I see your point, but I would concede that all square roots are the same type of irrational numbers.  root 2 is less weird than pi.

Comment: @brucesmitherson  That's why they called them irrational.  Or why that term is synonymous with something that makes no sense.

Comment: @Jiminion yes, it makes sense, but I am not an expert in history of mathematics